# Set state in componentDidMount outside of a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've read that I should not `setState` directly in `componentDidMount`, but setting it in a callback is fine (that's why it's the place for ajax calls).
The problem is that I set the state after parsing the search params like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  let price = 0;

  const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
  for (let param of query.entries()) {
    if (param[0] === 'price') {
      price = param[1];
    }
  }

  this.setState({ price: price });
}
```

I then do a **conditional rendering**: if the **price** isn't set, I render **nothing**.

I understand that this will cause 2 renders: The first one will be blank, and the second one will be the intended one, after the price is set.

So, is there any problem with calling `setState` directly inside `componentDidMount`? Is there a better alternative?

I don't want to use `componentWillMount` due to its recent deprecation (react 16.3).

Comment: why not to make it in `constructor`?

Comment: I totally missed that, thank you very much.I used `constructor(props) {` and then used `props` to get the location and all that stuff. Finally, I set `this.state =` the values I got. Works as intended.

Comment: AFAIK there is no reason not to use  ```setState``` directly inside ```componentDidMount```. However default state should be set as state = {} or inside a constructor if this is what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        price:false
    };
}
```

Now create a function

```
togglediv{(this.setState({price:!this.state.price})}
```

and you can use conditional rendering on the div which you want to show /hide